# Spring Boot builds OK, but Heroku deploy fails

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, maven, heroku

I've looked this up extensively and found no useful answer. I'm trying to deploy [this API](https://github.com/korrakeala/cashonline) with Heroku. It's a pre-existing GitHub repository, I followed Heroku's devcenter guidelines. I tried to deploy via Git and the Heroku Maven Plugin, and the result is the same: I can build it locally and everything is fine, but when I cd to `~/workspace/API/myapi/` and try to push it to Heroku doing `git push heroku main:main` I get:

```
Enumerating objects: 237, done.
Counting objects: 100% (237/237), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (179/179), done.
Writing objects: 100% (237/237), 91.06 KiB | 4.14 MiB/s, done.
Total 237 (delta 61), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 11... done
remote: -----> Executing Maven
remote:        $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
remote: ./mvnw: 219: ./mvnw: cannot open /tmp/build_f4dfb6d1/API/myapi/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties: No such file
remote: /tmp/build_f4dfb6d1/API/myapi/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar: No such file or directory
remote: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
remote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to myapiheroku.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/cashonlineheroku.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapiheroku.git'
```

- `/home/myuser/workspace/API/myapi/.mvn/wrapper/` contains the files
  `maven-wrapper.jar`, `maven-wrapper.properties` and
  `MavenWrapperDownloader.java`.
- `/home/myuser/workspace/API/myapi/system.properties` specifies
  `java.runtime.version=11`.
- `/home/myuser/.m2/repository/ar/com/api/myapi/` contains
  `myapi.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.
- You can find `pom.xml`,    `application.properties`, etc in the
  repository linked above.

What am I missing?
Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output shows that Heroku thinks you use Maven Wrapper for your project. Do you have a `mvnw` file in your project? Is it executable?

Comment: In /home/myuser/workspace/API/myapi/ there are two files like that: `mvnw` and `mvnw.cmd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a `mvnw` file in the root of your project directory but are missing other files required by Maven wrapper. Those usually reside in the `.mvn/wrapper` directory of your application. You might have deleted them.

You have two options:

1. Delete the other files for Maven Wrapper as well: `mvnw` and `mvnw.cmd`
2. Reinstall the missing files for Maven Wrapper: `mvn -N io.takari:maven:0.7.7:wrapper`

I'd go for option 2. Using the wrapper is generally preferred to ensure your project is run with the Maven version you expect.

Comment: Option 2 worked like a charm! thank you very much.